# ActiveAdmin Globalize create index filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, globalize

I'm using Globalize and ActiveAdmin, and I've now installed a gem from a fork of [ActiveAdminGlobalize](https://github.com/fabn/activeadmin-globalize)

Everything that is described in the readme is working, but I'd like to add a filter to the Active Admin Index.

So, for the model `stuff.rb`

```
class Stuff < ApplicationRecord
  translates :name
  active_admin_translates :name do
    validates_presence_of :name
  end
end
```

And the class in `app/admin/stuff.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Stuff do
  index do
    translation_status
    column :name 
  end

  filter :name

end
```

How do I make the filter :name to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using the regular ActiveAdmin gem and, after scratching my head for quite some time, found that the following works:

```
filter :translations_name_contains, as: :string
```

Of course you can change *name* with any other attributes you have translated with Globalize

```
filter :translations_title_contains, as: :string
```

To tie everything up nicely, I like to customize the label to avoid the default one AA creates:

```
filter :translations_title_contains, as: :string, label: "Search", placeholder: "Search page title..."
```

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, cause I'd like to keep the dropdown list, but still it helps. Thanks!

Comment: What dropdown list are you referring to @Tiago ?

Comment: Usually, when having a filter for countries, I prefer to have a dropdown list with the names of the existing countries, instead of a search box to look for them, @rorofromfrance